# Pentaho Data Integration: How to load and call method of external library JS at Pentaho(using in Modified Java Script Value Step)?

Tags: javascript, external, pentaho

Currently, I have a JS library that splits the User Agent string in the Request Heads into components like Browser, BrowserVersion, OperatingSystem, Device, OS, and so on.
I have a library (.js), who can help me how to add and use it in the Modified Java Script Value? Plz.
I want to see a simple example of it or something similar.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s3KG.png)

This is file js: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5fSakWz2DzTcjRjcG15UTFjYUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, how is the picture of the file meant to help us? Second, please put your code here, not linked on an external site especially one that will probably vanish. Otherwise your question is no use to other users. Third, show us what you have tried, otherwise we don't really know what your problem is. See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `LoadScriptFile(jsFilePath)` function in order to load execute a js script file on a `Modified JavaScript Value`.

You can call the function on a `Start Script` tab to avoid executing the entire script for every input row, then actually call the UAParser constructor on the `Transform Script` tab.

**Example:**

**Start Script** (executed once, just after the first input row arrives.)

In the transformation, right klick on the `Modified JavaScript Value` step where you want to insert a start script and select `Edit...` from the context menu. Or just doubleclick the step.

In the edit window there is the script area on the top right. To create a start script, right-click on the existing "Script 1" tab header, select "Add new", select the new tab, right-click on it, select "Set Start Script". Now you should have 2 script tabs, the first one is a usual "transform script", executed on every row, the second one is our start script, executed only one time, before the "transform script" for the first incoming row is executed.

This is the best place to load libraries and define functions.

Example code for the start script:

```
// assuming, that the ua-parser.js is in the transformation directory:
var transformationPath = getVariable("Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory", "");
var jsScriptPath = transformationPath + "/" + "ua-parser.js"
LoadScriptFile(jsScriptPath);
```

**Transform Script** (executed for every row)

```
// Use the field with User-Agent data instead of this hard-coded "Mozilla..." string:
var parsingResult = UAParser(
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0", "")
// converting the parsingResult to JSON string for demonstration purpose
var stepResult = JSON.stringify(parsingResult)
```

**Output:**

The stepResult column will have following value:

`{"ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0","browser":{"name":"Firefox","version":"52.0","major":"52"},"engine":{"version":"52.0","name":"Gecko"},"os":{"name":"Windows","version":"7"},"device":{},"cpu":{}}`

**Transformation steps xml (for PDI 7.0):**
Here is an xml, that shows how to integrate the script with input steps (using a Data grid as an input step).
You can copy the following xml, then paste it on your transformation canvas, then save it in the same folder where your ua-parser.js file is located, then the transformation should execute.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation-steps>
<steps>
  <step>
    <name>Data Grid</name>
    <type>DataGrid</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>userAgent</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <data>
      <line> <item>Mozilla&#x2f;5.0 &#x28;Windows NT 6.1&#x3b; WOW64&#x3b; rv&#x3a;52.0&#x29; Gecko&#x2f;20100101 Firefox&#x2f;52.0</item> </line>
    </data>
    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>144</xloc>
      <yloc>128</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Modified Java Script Value</name>
    <type>ScriptValueMod</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
    <partitioning>
      <method>none</method>
      <schema_name/>
    </partitioning>
    <compatible>N</compatible>
    <optimizationLevel>9</optimizationLevel>
    <jsScripts>      <jsScript>        <jsScript_type>0</jsScript_type>
        <jsScript_name>Script 1</jsScript_name>
        <jsScript_script>&#x2f;&#x2f;Script here&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;&#x2f;&#x2f; var parsingResult &#x3d; UAParser&#x28;&#x22;Mozilla&#x2f;5.0 &#x28;Windows NT 6.1&#x3b; WOW64&#x3b; rv&#x3a;52.0&#x29; Gecko&#x2f;20100101 Firefox&#x2f;52.0&#x22;, &#x22;&#x22;&#x29;&#xd;&#xa;var parsingResult &#x3d; UAParser&#x28;userAgent, &#x22;&#x22;&#x29;&#xd;&#xa;var stepResult &#x3d; JSON.stringify&#x28;parsingResult&#x29;</jsScript_script>
      </jsScript>      <jsScript>        <jsScript_type>1</jsScript_type>
        <jsScript_name>Item_0</jsScript_name>
        <jsScript_script>&#x2f;&#x2f;Script here&#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;var transformationPath &#x3d; getVariable&#x28;&#x22;Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory&#x22;, &#x22;&#x22;&#x29;&#x3b;&#xd;&#xa;var jsScriptPath &#x3d; transformationPath &#x2b; &#x22;&#x2f;&#x22; &#x2b; &#x22;ua-parser.js&#x22;&#xd;&#xa;LoadScriptFile&#x28;jsScriptPath&#x29;&#x3b;</jsScript_script>
      </jsScript>    </jsScripts>    <fields>      <field>        <name>stepResult</name>
        <rename>stepResult</rename>
        <type>String</type>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <replace>N</replace>
      </field>    </fields>    <cluster_schema/>
    <remotesteps>
      <input>
      </input>
      <output>
      </output>
    </remotesteps>
    <GUI>
      <xloc>320</xloc>
      <yloc>128</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
    </GUI>
    </step>

</steps>
<order>
    <hop>
      <from>Data Grid</from>
      <to>Modified Java Script Value</to>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
    </hop>

</order>
<notepads>
</notepads>
<step_error_handling>
</step_error_handling>
</transformation-steps>
```

**Note:**
Your library seems to work with PDI. But in general some libraries will not work with PDI, since PDI Javascript is quite different from JS in browsers/node.js: the PDI JS misses some browser-specific objects, like "window" or "document", and some objects in PDI could have unexpected behavior, since they may actually be unwrapped Java objects, not JavaScript objects.

Comment: Hello I'm try.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show photo of this example? I undertand but i can't run transform of example. :(

Comment: You can contact with me: https://www.facebook.com/dinhhungdigital.
I need you help :(

Comment: To make things easier, I've added an xml, which you can paste into a transformation to run the js. If it won't run, please check the errors/exceptions in the log. I don't have facebook account, sorry.

Comment: yeah, i can do it. :D Thank you so much.